# How can we monitor memory, threads, CPU etc. of a GraalVM native image during performance testing?

Tags: quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I want to run some performance tests against a Quarkus native image. In a traditional Java application I would use VisualVM to connect to the application and monitor its memory (young gen, old gen, etc.), CPU usage, threads and so on.

Since native images are now OS processes, is there a way to get insight information of the proccess equivalent to what we got with VisualVM or should we just stick to the OS information (CPU usage + memory)

Answer (score 0):

One option if you add the metrics extension is to fetch them and after plot in some way. Other option could be vmstat on unix, but you have them for the whole system.

If you deploy in a kubernetes environment prometheus fetch the information for you.